Arrayfomula with filter on entire column
I'm trying to build a Google Sheets formula to have a column that lists an array (can concatenate) of products ordered in the first order of a customer.
So for a any order with the same customer ID, the list of products will always be the same, corresponding to the first products they ever ordered.
This data is updated periodically so ideally the formula applies to the entire column.
Here is a sample sheet : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HvyeJPmAqcveA8rZ0IANdszGNWt9loRf08UTr3ChFjQ/edit#gid=1817801957
Is that even possible?
Thanks a lot
I tried building a formula using a filter and an arrayformula, it is shown as a tentative. Expected data is in column F but hard plugged.

From the [tag:google-sheets] tag wiki: Do NOT share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data. Use markdown TEXT tables instead. There are other valuable suggestions in that tag wiki. Please review it and then [edit] your post. Also, you'll find your experiences at SO will be much better if you take the time to complete the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

you can arrive in the same destination by taking multiple other routes as well. for example:
=VSTACK("first_skus", BYROW(C2:C, LAMBDA(c, IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1,
 QUERY(A2:D, "select A where D = 'First-time' and C = "&c, ))))))


where:

VSTACK can be exchanged for {} array brackets
BYROW can be exchanged for MAP
IFERROR can be exchanged for IFNA
TEXTJOIN can be exchanged for JOIN
QUERY can be exchanged for FILTER


={"first_skus"; MAP(C2:C, LAMBDA(c, IFNA(JOIN(", ",
 FILTER(A2:A, D2:D="First-time", C2:C=c)))))}



you can even omit IFNA in your sample spreadsheet (but better leave it in your real sheet as fail-safe)



You can use MAP
={
  "first_skus";
   map(C2:C,lambda(c,ifna(textjoin(", ",1,
     filter(A2:A,D2:D="First-time",C2:C=c)))))
 }

